# How can get the information of the related id based on the defined variable jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here's my html code:

```
<span id="test">This is span!</span>
```

Here is my javascript:

```
var foo_text = $("#test").html();
```

How can I get the span ID based on the var `foo_text`?
Thanks.

Comment: `$("#" + foo_text)` ?

Comment: Your question is a bit not clear. Can you elaborate it with an example?

Comment: switch() rules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

[:contains()](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/): select all elements that contain the specified text.

```js
var foo_text = $("#test").html();
var id = $('body :contains(' + foo_text + ')').attr('id');
console.log('The span ID based on the var foo_text is: ' + id);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<span id="test">This is span!</span>
```

Comment: If the tag was input and I only get the value of it, how can I trace the ID of the input itself?

Comment: @OrlandoSilaen Sorry for the delay. Snippet updated. If you need to select any tag inside body you can use as selector: **'body :contains(' + foo_text + ')'**. If you don't specify **body** you will select any tag in the page, including the header section. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

This way:

```
var foo_text = $("#test").html();
var id = '';

switch (foo_text) {
    case 'This is span!':
        id = $(this).attr('id');
        break;
}
```

Comment: He means using the variable `foo_text` as a way to find the span and then the id

Comment: edited. switch foo_text and if it matches whatever you want, extract its ID tag using .attr()